# magento whitelisted blocks are not displaying at fronend

Tags: magento-enterprise, magento-1, supee-6788

I have applied patch 6788 to magento EE 1.13 and also added block to white list but blocks are not displaying on home page

[image]

Please help

Comment: Check your site logs. If issue is related to Patch, there should be an entry in there.

Comment: @Prateek no any error in log

Comment: If it's not a live site, try enabling developer mode. If it's a live site, you can enable it with IP conditioning. That should give you the reason for why you are not seeing your block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you so much all of you for your time, my problem was with magestore bannerslider module. after digging into this I found the solution on this url

https://magentary.com/kb/magestore-bannerslider-broken-after-supee-6788-or-magento-upgrade/

error was :

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ‘.`value)` =
>   ‘0’) AND (`start_time`

To solve SQL error change line 60 in app/code/community/Magestore/Bannerslider/Model/Mysql4/Banner/Collection.php as shown in the diff below:

```
--- Bannerslider/Model/Mysql4/Banner/Collection.php
+++ Bannerslider/Model/Mysql4/Banner/Collection.php
@@ -59,3 +59,3 @@
             }
-            return parent::addFieldToFilter("IF($field.value IS NULL, main_table.$field, $field.value)", $condition);
+           $this->getSelect()->where("IF($field.value IS NULL, main_table.$field, $field.value) = 0");
         }
```

**Make sure that bannerslider/default block is whitelisted at CMS > Pages or CMS > Static Blocks**